# Crossdomain ajax request doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax

All browsers except Firefox are work great with the request. Firefox show this:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url]. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. [url]

Htaccess on the server with html:

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

```
var urlPage = 'https://страница,где должна происходить магия', 
      queryLink = 'https://ссылка с айди/?id=', 
      linkPartners = 'https://ссылка на html на сервере.html';


$.ajax({

  url: linkPartners,
  success: function(html){

    if (urlPage == window.location.href) {
        $(".orange-box .blink").html(html).css({
          "background": "none",
          "padding": "0"
        });
        $(".orange-box").css('background', 'none');
        $(".ob-content").css('background', 'none');
    };

    $('.table-partners tbody a').attr('href',function(){
       linkSub = this.href + $('#inner_link').data('link');
       return linkSub;
    });
  }
});




$.ajax({    


  url: queryLink + $('#inner_link').data('link'),
  success: function(html){


    if(urlPage == window.location.href ) {
      if (html != "") {

        var objJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
        if (objJSON != null) {
          var balance = objJSON.sum;     

          if (balance != null) {
              $('.profileData h4').append('<div class="bal-left">Действительны до <a href="#" target="_blank">1.10.2015</a>: <strong>' + balance + ' </strong></div>');
              return;
          } 
        }
      };
 }
 $('.profileData h4').append('<span style="display:none;"></span>');
}
});
```

Comment: Are you running this from a server, or from the file system?

Comment: for crossdomain access, you need to pass the `datatype` as `jsonp` in your ajax call.

Comment: @dreamweiver no you don't

Comment: @zerkms: `Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options.` ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. so if you dont use it then your ajax request will behave differenlty.

Comment: Indeed, but you *don't have to* switch to jsonp. Cross-domain requests can be performed without jsonp